Why does modal created with intercepting routes close only on router.back()?
I created modal with intercepting routes and I want close it with router.push(someUrl) or <Link href={someURL}>. The problem is that only router.back() works. Other methods change the url but the modal remains open. I tried to add [...catchAll]/page.tsx like in docs but it didn't help.
My routes structure:

modal.tsx:
'use client';

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { FaXmark } from 'react-icons/fa6';
import styles from './modal.module.scss';

export default function Modal({
  children,
  backURL,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  backURL: string;
}) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const closeModal = () => (backURL ? router.push(backURL) : router.back());

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.overlay}>
        <div className={styles.modal}>
          <button className={styles.close_btn} onClick={closeModal}>
            <FaXmark />
          </button>
          {/* doesn't close modal */}
          <Link href={backURL} className={styles.close_btn}>
            <FaXmark />
          </Link>
          {/* doesn't close modal */}
          <div>{children}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

[...catchAll]/page.tsx:
export default function CatchAll() {
  return null;
}

layout.tsx:
export default function Layout({
  children,
  modal,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  modal: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
      {modal}
    </div>
  );
}

After clicking on the close button the URL changes from /blogs/[id]/comments to blogs/[id] but modal remains open as in the picture:

The Modal close only if I use router.back()
